# Can some one explain me what the startup code is which automatically gets added to C programs by the compiler

Tags: c, gcc, startup

Can some one explain me what `startup code` is which automatically gets added to C programs by the compiler and can someone provide me original documentations which describe about the `startup code` which gets added to a C program automatically by the compiler.

I searched the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) for `startup code` which gets added to C programs automatically but I found no results.

And I searched the [gcc compiler documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.pdf) about startup code but didn't find any results. Can someone please tell me where in the `C standard` and `gcc compiler` the `startup code` is described or can some one provide me the original accurate documentation which describes `C startup code`

Comment: [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0)

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you i read this but i need the original documentation which describe `C startup code`

Comment: `I need the original documentation` There is no such thing. The startup code is implementation defined - each compiler has it's own set of rules how to setup the C environment. There is no documentation "how to do it" and standard do not document that. Standard specify end results. Like "all variables with static storage duraction shall be initialized to 0 or NULL". They don't specify _how_, they specify end result, the state. I do not know - as to what "documentation" you are referring to? You can read about how a specific hardware operates - for example how x86 works. Or calling conventions.

Comment: @KamilCuk yes thank you but atleast the `implementation` should document about C startup code is there any documentation about C startup code provided by the gcc compiler

Comment: these links might help - http://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/glibc/startup.html.  This is specific for glibc.  In addition, you can look at the source code - https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/i386/start.S  It is well commented

Comment: @Kevin The start up code comes from glibc not the compiler.  You may want to look through the glibc documentation.

Comment: @Kevin It is not even necessary added by the compiler. It is only the case on hosted environments. On embedded systems you will often see custom startup code written as a part of the project. (gcc `-nostartfiles` flag)